# Creating tasks as part of a build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, task

I currently have a project set up in Bamboo that has various tasks attached to it ranging from: source code checkouts, scripts and commands.

I would like to transition over to Jenkins and perform the same action and found that Pipelines may be what I am looking for.

Can anyone provide me with a basic understanding of how I can create a Pipeline or freestyle job in Jenkins with sequential tasks that are executed as part of a build? A project in Bamboo has a plan with various tasks and I would like to replicate the same thing in Jenkins.

Here is an example of what my Bamboo tasks look like:

[image: Bamboo]

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start with [Getting Started With Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/pipeline/getting-started-pipelines/).

Comment: The freestyle job looks like it may be able to perform what I need. The first step was just getting a source code checkout but I receive an error when I enter my repository URL. Not sure if it has anything to do with the fact that I am using GitLab

Comment: Don't use Freestyle jobs, that's the old job type. Use Pipeline jobs, if you want pipelines.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. So would my code in the Pipeline script represent all of my tasks that are in my Bamboo plan?

Comment: Yes, that would be one pipeline consisting of roughly the same stages (you could potentially parallelize the Build+Export stages for x86 and x64.

Comment: Is there any way that I could message you for more help? Don't want to lengthen this comment section too much and you've been of much help so far

Comment: Give it a try, come back if you encounter problems that you weren't able to solve with the information available in the internet. Include your code then (see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Hey @StephenKing, I just wanted to let you know that I was able to checkout code from a remote repository using the freestyle job template. I was having credential issues with the Pipeline template, specifically, I did not find out how I can enter my credentials for SSH or HTTPS whereas the freestyle job made it easier to understand. I am going to continue building out my tasks in this way and will try and implement it using the Pipeline template once I am done.